# Running mongoimport inside a Docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm using the official MongoDB Docker image, and trying to initialize a Mongo database by placing the following script under `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`:

```bash
tail -n +1 ../datasets/things.csv | mongoimport --db=test --collection=things --type=csv --fieldFile=../datasets/fields.csv --username=root --password=example
```

This is what my `compose.yml` looks like:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: test
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mongo/datasets:/datasets
      - ./docker/mongo/db_init.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db_init.sh
```

The DB is not populated, and when I drop in into the container to run manually the script I get the **error*:

```
root@44254ca5310f:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d# . db_init.sh 
2022-12-28T14:46:51.509+0000    error connecting to host: could not connect to server: connection() error occurred during connection handshake: auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1": (AuthenticationFailed) Authentication failed.
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit didn't help

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit oh sorry, in my question is not reflected but, I tried adding the ``authenticationDatabase`` at the end of the uri string (`mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017/test`) and it didn't help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @WernfriedDomscheit for sending me down the right track. The official docs for the `mongo` docker image refer to the `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE` as the name of a database to be used for creation scripts in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*.js`.
Since I used `test` as a value in my `compose.yml`, I thought that was the name to use as value for the `authenticationDatabase` parameter. But no, it must be equal to `admin`. So there are twoish ways for specifying it:

```
tail -n +1 ../datasets/things.csv | mongoimport --collection=things --type=csv --fieldFile=../datasets/fields.csv mongodb://root:example@mongo:27017/admin
```

That would import the collection into `admin` database. But if we want to import into the `test` database, we have to run:

```
tail -n +1 ../datasets/things.csv | mongoimport --collection=things --type=csv --fieldFile=../datasets/fields.csv --username=root --password=example --authenticationDatabase=admin
```

Also, using `--db` allows us to specify the name of the database.